# Using Hibernate i am getting Exception while updating its in loop

Tags: java, hibernate, struts-1

I am Using hibernate. I am inserting data into two tables and updating one table.
While updating I am getting Exception - as the object references an unsaved transient instance - `save the transient instance before flushing: com.treamis.inventory.goodsReceived.GoodsRecieved..`
If I remove update related code, its working fine

```
try {
            SalesInventoryDAO dao = new SalesInventoryDAO();
            sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction tr = sess.beginTransaction();
            GoodsRecievedForm item = (GoodsRecievedForm) form;
            GoodsRecieved bk = new GoodsRecieved();
            bk.setGoodsId(item.getGoodsId());
            InventoryOrder order = (InventoryOrder) sess.get(InventoryOrder.class, item.getOrderNo());
            bk.setOrderNo(order);
//            if (order.getQuotation().getQuotationNo() != null) {
//                bk.setQuotation(order.getQuotation().getQuotationNo());
//            } else {
//                bk.setQuotation(null);
//            }

            java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(item.getRecievedDate());
            java.sql.Date temp1 = new java.sql.Date(temp.getTime());
            bk.setRecievedDate(temp1);
            bk.setOrderQty(order.getTotalqty());
            bk.setReceivedPersonName(item.getReceivedPersonName());
            bk.setReceivedQty(item.getReceivedQty());
            bk.setConditionOfMaterial(item.getConditionOfMaterial());
            UserEntity msg;
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            msg = (UserEntity) session.getAttribute("user");
            bk.setAddedBy(msg);
            bk.setAddedDate(new Date());
            int[] item1111 = item.getGoodsDetails();
            String[] productre = item.getGoodsDetailsName();
            float proqty[] = item.getGoodsDetailsQty();
            float price[] = item.getGoodsDetailsPrice();
            float receivedqty[] = item.getReceivedquantity();
            GoodsReceivedDetails mb;
            Set<GoodsReceivedDetails> purDetails = new HashSet<GoodsReceivedDetails>();
            for (int i = 0; i < productre.length; i++) {
                mb = new GoodsReceivedDetails();
                mb.setGoodsDetailsName(productre[i]);
                mb.setGoodsDetailsQty(proqty[i]);
                mb.setGoodsDetailsPrice(price[i]);
                mb.setReceivedquantity(receivedqty[i]);
                //System.out.println("productre" + productre[i]);
                int id3 = item1111[i];
                //System.out.println("id3id3id3id3" + id3);
                // int id3 = Integer.parseInt(productre[i]);
                Item idf = (Item) sess.get(Item.class, id3);
                System.out.println("mb.getReceivedquantity()" + mb.getReceivedquantity());
                float qty = (idf.getItemStock() + mb.getReceivedquantity());
                System.out.println("qtyqty" + qty);
                mb.setItemId(idf);
                Query qry = sess.createQuery("UPDATE Item set itemStock='" + qty + "' where itemId='" + idf.getItemId() + "'");
                qry.executeUpdate();
//                dao.updateitem(qty, idf,sess);
                //dao.updateitem(idf);
                mb.setGoodsId(bk);
                sess.save(mb);
                purDetails.add(mb);
            }
            bk.setGoodsDetails(purDetails);
            sess.save(bk);
            tr.commit();
            //System.out.println("comming");
//            List ls = gdao.getOrderItems(order.getOrderId());
//            for (Iterator it = ls.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
//                InventoryOrderDetails inv = (InventoryOrderDetails) it.next();
//                gdao.updateitem(inv.getItemId().getItemStock() + bk.getReceivedQty(), inv.getItemId());
//            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sess.close();
        }
```

This is my stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.treamis.inventory.goodsReceived.GoodsRecieved
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.findDirty(TypeFactory.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.findDirty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3123)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.isUpdateNecessary(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:969)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1136)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:94)
    at com.treamis.inventory.goodsReceived.AddGoodsRecievedAction.addGoodsReceived(AddGoodsRecievedAction.java:112)
    at com.treamis.inventory.goodsReceived.AddGoodsRecievedAction.execute(AddGoodsRecievedAction.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.treamis.academics.examlist.SessionFilterServelet.doFilter(SessionFilterServelet.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is One Entity GoodsReceived:

```
@Entity
public class GoodsRecieved implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int goodsId;
    @OneToOne
    private InventoryOrder orderNo;
//    private String quotation;
    private float orderQty;
    private String receivedPersonName;
    private float receivedQty;
    private String conditionOfMaterial;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date recievedDate;
    @OneToOne
    private UserEntity addedBy;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date addedDate;
    @OneToOne
    private UserEntity modifiedBy;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedDate;
      @OneToMany(targetEntity = GoodsReceivedDetails.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "goodsDetails", referencedColumnName = "goodsId")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<GoodsReceivedDetails> goodsDetails;

    public int getGoodsId() {
        return goodsId;
    }

    public void setGoodsId(int goodsId) {
        this.goodsId = goodsId;
    }

    public InventoryOrder getOrderNo() {
        return orderNo;
    }

    public void setOrderNo(InventoryOrder orderNo) {
        this.orderNo = orderNo;
    }

    public float getOrderQty() {
        return orderQty;
    }

    public void setOrderQty(float orderQty) {
        this.orderQty = orderQty;
    }

    public String getReceivedPersonName() {
        return receivedPersonName;
    }

    public void setReceivedPersonName(String receivedPersonName) {
        this.receivedPersonName = receivedPersonName;
    }

    public float getReceivedQty() {
        return receivedQty;
    }

    public void setReceivedQty(float receivedQty) {
        this.receivedQty = receivedQty;
    }

//    public String getQuotation() {
//        return quotation;
//    }
//
//    public void setQuotation(String quotation) {
//        this.quotation = quotation;
//    }

    public Date getRecievedDate() {
        return recievedDate;
    }

    public void setRecievedDate(Date recievedDate) {
        this.recievedDate = recievedDate;
    }

    public UserEntity getAddedBy() {
        return addedBy;
    }

    public void setAddedBy(UserEntity addedBy) {
        this.addedBy = addedBy;
    }

    public Date getAddedDate() {
        return addedDate;
    }

    public void setAddedDate(Date addedDate) {
        this.addedDate = addedDate;
    }

    public UserEntity getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(UserEntity modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    public Date getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    public String getConditionOfMaterial() {
        return conditionOfMaterial;
    }

    public void setConditionOfMaterial(String conditionOfMaterial) {
        this.conditionOfMaterial = conditionOfMaterial;
    }

    public Set<GoodsReceivedDetails> getGoodsDetails() {
        return goodsDetails;
    }

    public void setGoodsDetails(Set<GoodsReceivedDetails> goodsDetails) {
        this.goodsDetails = goodsDetails;
    }   
}
```

This is My another Entity GoodsReceivedDetails :

```
    @Entity
    public class GoodsReceivedDetails implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int goodsDetailsId;
    private String goodsDetailsName;
    private float goodsDetailsQty;
    private float goodsDetailsPrice;
    private float receivedquantity;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "goodsId")
    private GoodsRecieved goodsId;
    @OneToOne()
    private Item itemId;

    public int getGoodsDetailsId() {
        return goodsDetailsId;
    }

    public void setGoodsDetailsId(int goodsDetailsId) {
        this.goodsDetailsId = goodsDetailsId;
    }

    public String getGoodsDetailsName() {
        return goodsDetailsName;
    }

    public void setGoodsDetailsName(String goodsDetailsName) {
        this.goodsDetailsName = goodsDetailsName;
    }

    public float getGoodsDetailsQty() {
        return goodsDetailsQty;
    }

    public void setGoodsDetailsQty(float goodsDetailsQty) {
        this.goodsDetailsQty = goodsDetailsQty;
    }

    public float getGoodsDetailsPrice() {
        return goodsDetailsPrice;
    }

    public void setGoodsDetailsPrice(float goodsDetailsPrice) {
        this.goodsDetailsPrice = goodsDetailsPrice;
    }

    public GoodsRecieved getGoodsId() {
        return goodsId;
    }

    public void setGoodsId(GoodsRecieved goodsId) {
        this.goodsId = goodsId;
    }

    public Item getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(Item itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public float getReceivedquantity() {
        return receivedquantity;
    }

    public void setReceivedquantity(float receivedquantity) {
        this.receivedquantity = receivedquantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your code for updateitem() and the stacktrace

Comment: can you share mapping details for `GoodsReceivedDetails` and `GoodsRecieved`?

Comment: I showed all my models could anybody please assist me,thanku

Comment: @Venkatesh your code for saving entity is quite large. Can you please remove unnecessary code or highlight the code which is giving error?

Answer (score 0):

I think You have wrong ORM definition try below

You have this in

```
   @OneToMany(targetEntity = GoodsReceivedDetails.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "goodsDetails", referencedColumnName = "goodsId")
   @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<GoodsReceivedDetails> goodsDetails;
```

Try this

```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "goodsId", targetEntity = GoodsReceivedDetails.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Set<GoodsReceivedDetails> goodsDetails;
```

As you put  `@JoinColumn` in `GoodsRecieved` class. You shouldn't put it for Bi-directional relation. You should use `mappedBy` attribute.

If you would like to have a bi-directional relation `GoodsRecieved` and `GoodsReceivedDetails`, then as `GoodsReceivedDetails` many side (target) entity, he should be the relation definition OWNER, so he should define `@JoinColumn` and non owner side i.e. `GoodsRecieved` he should use `mappedBy` attribute to say it is bi-directional not a NEW relation definition.

In your case you have define `Two Uni-directional mappings` :( . May be this could be the issue.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
    ...
    mb.setGoodsId(bk);
    sess.save(mb);
    purDetails.add(mb);
}
bk.setGoodsDetails(purDetails);
sess.save(bk);
tr.commit();
...
```

You are trying to persist `mb`, before persisting `bk`.
Try to persist `bk` first.

Comment: Could u please elaborate me in that bk and mb

Comment: The code I posted is a snippet of your code, just to highlight the point where I think the mistake is.

Comment: I think you could simply try to put `sess.save(bk);` before your for loop.

Comment: if put like that foreign key storing null

Answer (score 0):

Below annotation for `goodsId` property in `GoodsReceivedDetails` says that, you have a column `goodsId` which is a foreign key referring to `GoodsRecieved`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "goodsId")
private GoodsRecieved goodsId;
```

So you don't need to have `@JoinColumn` for `goodsDetails` in `GoodsRecieved`. Change that mapping to this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "goodsId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<GoodsReceivedDetails> goodsDetails;
```

Here `@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)` introduces transitive persistence. With this, when you  instantiate a new `GoodsReceivedDetails` and add it to a `GoodsRecieved`, the `GoodsReceivedDetails` should become persistent immediately. You don't need to explicitly make a `GoodsReceivedDetails` persistent by calling `save()` on the Session interface.

So you can replace this block of code:

```
mb.setGoodsId(bk);
sess.save(mb);
purDetails.add(mb);
}
bk.setGoodsDetails(purDetails);
sess.save(bk);
```

with this:

```
mb.setGoodsId(bk);
purDetails.add(mb);
}
bk.setGoodsDetails(purDetails);
sess.save(bk);
```

The cascade annotation tells Hibernate to make any new `GoodsReceivedDetails` instance persistent (that is, save it in the database) if the `GoodsReceivedDetails` is referenced by a persistent `GoodsRecieved`.

Comment: i used like that but if i remove ses.save(mb) its not inserting to the database table:goodsreceiveddetailstable

Comment: i don't think you need to set `bk.setGoodsId(item.getGoodsId());`. comment this and try.

Comment: thnku so much i got output thnks for helping me